# Default Colour on Radio Buttons

Tags: forms, pdf, adobe

I am putting together a simple form for a friend and they want when a button is selected to change from amber, too green.

I have attached PDF to give an idea of what I am looking for. Much like a data validation on excel, but for the life of me I cannot figure out how to do it.

Default: Amber
when clicked: Green

[image: Radio Button]

Answer (score 0):

It is certainly possible with PDFs to do that since the appearance of a form field is defined by arbitrary drawing instructions.

However, whether you can do that *with a PDF editor* wholely depends on the capabilities of the PDF editor.

Comment: I have Adobe Pro (Creative Cloud)

Comment: I don't know the features of Adobe Pro but you should be able to define a background color of the widget. However, that would generally be used for both states. What you can try, if possible, to tell Adobe that the unselected button should have *no* visual appearance and the selected button the needed background color. Then draw the unselected button yourself onto the page. This is a work-around but may work.